# Searching in a time range

Tags: xml, excel

I am currently using a formula that matches certain criteria from one sheet to another and returns a value. The problem I am having is that it will only return a true value if the time is exactly the same on both sheets. I need it to look a the time on the first sheet and check if it matches the time on the second sheet plus or minus say 10 minutes. Here's the code I am using.  FYI (Sheet1, 1=Date, 2=Time, 3=RefNo)(Sheet2, 1=Date, 2=Time, 3=RefNo, 4=RefNo)

```
If UCase(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value) = UCase(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 1).Value) Then
If UCase(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value) = UCase(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 2).Value) Then
If UCase(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Value) = UCase(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 4).Value) Or UCase(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 4).Value) = UCase(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 4).Value) Then
Worksheets("Workings").Cells(i, 1).Value = UCase(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 12).Value)
Worksheets("Workings").Cells(i, 2).Value = UCase(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 9).Value)
```

I cannot find a reference to this problem on any forum and am completely stumped, I am sure there is a simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming VBA, that the cells are in a date/time format & that i is their address;

```
Abs(DateDiff("N", Worksheets("Workings").Cells(i, 1).Value, Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1).Value))
```

Will return a positive integer representing the number of minutes difference between the 2 times.

I created a blank workbook and;

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 2).Value = "15:00:00"
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 2).Value = "15:00:00"
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 2).Value = "15:00:00"

Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 2).Value = "15:05:00"
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 2).Value = "15:59:00"
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(3, 2).Value = "15:00:00"

For i = 1 To 3
    If (Abs(DateDiff("N", Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value, Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 2).Value)) < 10) Then
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 3) = "in range"
    End If
Next
```

Works for me, I see on sheet2;

```
15:05   in range
15:59   
15:00   in range
```

Comment: Hi Alex K, Sorry i may not have been too clear in what i require. the first if function checks if the dates match in there respective columns, the second checks the time and the third the ref. if the Ref, date and time match it returns a value, if all matches but the time, as it is one minute out, the cells will remain blank. i need this formula to allow a little lea way on the timings (10 Mins)

Comment: Can you not just replace the time equality check;
`If UCase(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value) = UCase(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 2).Value) Then`
with the 10 minute window check:
`if (Abs(DateDiff("N", Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value, Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1).Value)) > 10) Then`

Comment: Alex K, i have just tried this and it immediatly finishes running and returns no values at all?

Comment: Oops I used (i, 1) should be (i,2), also ensure they are in a valid date|time format

Comment: Alex K, yes i noticed and adjusted but it does not seems to do what i need. is there any more info i could provide that may help?

Comment: Thanks Alex K, that explains it.